# Is it possible to extract part of a formula in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was wondering if it is possible to extract *part* of a formula in either Microsoft Excel or Google sheets. I ask this because I already have a worksheet filled so it is not viable for me to begin with the formula in two separate cells.

For example, if I have the formula `=(1-7)-(1-4)`, is there anyway for me to extract and evaluate the `(1-7)` part in a different cell? A regex solution would be preferred, but fixed number of character solution would be okay too.

Comment: Maybe start with `=FORMULATEXT()`

Comment: I also see you can write a custom =EVALUATE function using VBA, that may be what I end up doing -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EVALUATE()` function directly in mainstream Excel, no VBA needed.

You use it in the formula for a Named Range. Then use the in-cell formula of `=horse` (if you named the range "horse"... of course... (forgive me, I've waited a while to use that and probably no one will get it anyway...))

So work up the formula you need, and carefully consider whether to use absolute references in it or not. Write it, then copy it to the clipboard. Go to the Named Range creator and create your Named Range, type "=EVALUATE(" paste the formula, and type a closing parenthesis.

Then just type "=Named Range" to have it work as you wished in your question.

Full absolute reference ("$R$C") is good if the source is always the same cell. Partial-and non-absolute references are needed otherwise. However, they are tricky to create as you have to select the cell that is relative to the source in the same way you will use it:  if sourcing A1, for example, and wanting the result in D9, then select D9 and make sure you refer to A1 as you write the formula.

Comment: i use excel 2016 for osx, and it doesn't have an evaluate function, but I get the gist, thanks